# Add Synonym to a tag that is already a Synonym of a master is allowed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

On SF I created a synonym (named thisisatestpleasedeclines
) of the tag [network](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=network) but network is already a synonym of [networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=networking)

I guess this should not be allowed, on the network tag page I think it should say that this tag has already a master.

Is this the intended behaviour? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Good catch. Any kind of chaining is ridiculous.

Comment: Note that chains can also come into existing the opposite way around. On SO there is a synonym [thread] -> [threads] in place, and now there is a new proposed synonym [threads] -> [multithreading]. What would happen to [thread] tags if this is established? To make matters worse, you can also build synonym circles...

Comment: I don't think you can build circles, I tried and this was not working but I'm only ~6k on SF, may be with > 10k (as you) you can ?

Comment: @radius: If the tags have the same number of posts, it is possible (I just tried it and was able to suggest a [programming-related] <-> [non-programming-related] cycle [here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)).

Comment: Another example on SO: `ms-word` is a synonym for `microsoft-word`, but `microsoft-word` is a synonym for `msword`.

Comment: chaining is trouble ... I should improve the error messages

Answer (score 3):

Very confusing indeed.

I just amended the tag synonym system so it disallows chains. **chains can no longer be proposed**, if you propose a chain pointing at `foo` this error will show up:

> A synonym from `foo` to `bar` exists, chains are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely be disallowed.

However, if questions involved in a tag synonym are automatically retagged, the restriction of not allowing more popular tags to be made synonyms of less popular tags should take care of the bulk of this validation (because the target would always have 0 questions).

It still could be exploited, although it's probably just easier to implement a check, if for nothing else but sanity.

Answer (score 0):

And chaining evidently does not propagate through the system. At the [sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3122/revisions), I added the tag `[always-hydrogen-in-iceland]`, which got converted to `[always-friday-in-iceland]`. However, `[always-friday-in-iceland]` is itself a synonym for `[fun]`, but as you can see from the revision summary, the change didn't go through.