# Cannot use tag 'games', it is changed to tag 'game' and refused since it's new

Tags: support, tags

Trying to create a new question tagged [games](/questions/tagged/games) fails, as it is seen as [game](/questions/tagged/game) and thought as a new tag. Please fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I removed the [games](/questions/tagged/games) -> [game](/questions/tagged/game) synonym, and added [games](/questions/tagged/games) to the synonyms for [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development).  That should clear up the specific problem you reported.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response =)

Answer (score 7):

The [games](/questions/tagged/games) tag is a synonym of [game](/questions/tagged/game), which is a synonym of [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development). There's a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59256/add-synonym-to-a-tag-that-is-already-a-synonym-of-a-master-is-allowed) in which synonyms of synonyms are not handled properly -- in theory when you submit it should replace your [games](/questions/tagged/games) tag with a [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) tag, but it doesn't. For now you can manually tag the post [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) and it should work fine